# Maven cannot get artifact from my local repository

Tags: maven

Trying to get the follwing JAR from my local/internal repository:

```
httpclient-4.3.1.jar
```

Maven fails with Error:

```
ArtifactDescriptionException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.....
```

It works fine with every single other jar but it fails on this apache one. No idea why. Tried clearing `.m2\repository`, upgrading Maven, eclipse, re-uploading, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try mvn -U clean install command.

It checks for updates and releases and snapshots on remote repository."-U" forces to check the updates.

Comment: try it where? I'm using eclipse

Comment: If you have the m2e plugin, then you can go to Maven -> Update Project... . The next dialog will have an option to force updates of snapshots and releases.

Comment: tried, didn't work. funny thing is if I use "maven central" it will get the jar file just fine. It's not getting it locally. I don't understand it.

Comment: Can you try by using cmd goto the root directory of your project and execute the command I have mentioned in the answer.